# Is there a function to obfuscate a PostGIS point or geometry?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am looking for a function, perhaps a Perlin noise implementation or something similar, for PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

Does such a thing exist in core PostGIS?

If not, does such a function exist an shared repo/blog post/napkin?

Comment: See https://medium.com/gisire/how-to-distort-geodata-and-why-you-should-2631eb98d84d